# Add a custom field when adding / editing a page / post in admin panel

Tags: wp-admin, metabox, customization

I create a new theme and I the page / post is divided to:

- Title
- Slogan
- Content

I want to add a slogan field in the admin panel, where the user adds or edits a post or page.
After I will use in update_option function.. just the part of adding this is the problem.
I think there is a function or filter which does it but I don't know which.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you are looking for a way how to add a **meta box** (that's what it's called in WordPress terminology) to your page edit screen. Please checkout the answer to a related question: [How to add meta boxes to the 'Add new post' screen?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6289/how-to-add-meta-boxes-to-the-add-new-post-screen/6291#6291)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Advanced Custom Fields Plugin. It allows you to create whatever type of field you wish, and then adds it to posts or pages (or both). After that, it is pretty simple to call within the wordpress loop.